# Forcefully turning off BLE device connected to Android app fires onConnectionStateChange with status 8

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I have an Android app that uses the BLE API to connect to a BLE device. If I connect to the device and then turn off the power of the device after a few seconds I get this line in the logcat:

```
11-15 12:33:07.977 27829-27847/com.mycompany.platform.hellodev D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=6 device=55:1C:6C:86:8A:F8
```

which then invokes our `BluetoothGattCallback` callback `onConnectionStateChange` with `status=8` and `newStatus=0`

I can't find any public documentation that says what `status=8` means.

Is it right to assume that if `newStatus=0` is passed it means the BLE device has disconnected?

Answer (score 8):

> I can't find any public documentation that says what status=8 means.

It means that you lost the connection link(LINK_LOSS) due to no response from remote device or Timeout happened.

> Is it right to assume that if newStatus=0 is passed it means the BLE device has disconnected?

Yes if newStatus is 0, means CONNECTION state is **idle**, and device is now disconnected.

Comment: Can you confirm this is the case with status 8? surprisingly this only appears API version > 19.

Comment: @NowaConcordia Absolutely, its loss of connection link(generally known as link loss).

Comment: Thank you Ankit for sharing about status 8.

Comment: @AAnkit do you have an official source that verifies your claim? Thanks!